# How to indicate progress percetage in progressbar?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to show the progress percentage  in progress bar.I donot want to use progress indicator.Is there anything by which i can add progress percentage in progress bar of javafx.Or i have to write some custom thing. Apart from this i want to make the progress bar eleptical or round shape instead of square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this question ...By adding stack pane  and above it i can add text and progressbar will solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to implement a progressbar with the needed feature by your own. https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4391775 Jewelsea gives an example of an implementation of a progress bar that shows custom text.